# Laravel5:Redirect::to() outside link NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm developing a Laravel 5 app, I have this route

```
Route::get('/go','UrlController@index');
```

and in this UrlController.php,I have this index method

```
public function index(){
    return Redirect::to('www.google.com',302);
}
```

when I test this url `http://localhost:8000/go`
 it just change to `http://localhost:8000/www.google.com` and have this error `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`
so what the problem is , Thanks

Comment: try add http:// in front of the www.google.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add protocol before the www.google.com

```
public function index(){
    return Redirect::to('https://www.google.com',302);
}
```